# Не изменяется переменная C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, codemirror

Метод SetGuns не может изменить переменную.
тип переменных Gun

```
protected virtual void Awake()
{
    var test = Instantiate(GameManager.Knife);
    SlotKnife = test.GetComponent<Gun>();
// False False
// Переменная изменятся
    Debug.Log($"{SlotKnife == null} {test.GetComponent<Gun>() == null}");
}

public void SetGuns()
{
    var test = GameManager.InstantiateGun(GameManager.Knife);
    SlotMainGun = test;
// True False
// Переменная НЕ изменятся
    Debug.Log($"{SlotMainGun == null} {test == null}");
    SlotSecondaryGun = GameManager.InstantiateGun(GameManager.Glock);
    SlotKnife = GameManager.InstantiateGun(GameManager.Knife);
}
```

```
//Класс GameManager
    public static Gun InstantiateGun(GameObject prefab)
    {
        GameObject spawnedGun = Instantiate(prefab);
        NetworkServer.Spawn(spawnedGun);

        Gun gunComponent = spawnedGun.GetComponent<Gun>();
// выведет ошибку если возвращаемое значение null (в консоле ничего нет)
        if (gunComponent == null) Debug.LogError("Gun component is null!");
        return gunComponent;
    }
```

```
//Класс NetManager
//этот метод спавнит игрока
public void ServerAddPlayer()
{
    ...
    logicBase.SetGuns();
}
```

Comment: А что за класс в первом блоке? Или это 2 разных скрипта? Не совсем понятна архитектура из обрезков кода. `SlotMainGun` - это что, свойство, поле? Почему оставили в секрете? Переменные - это только внутри метода что объявляется, все что является членами классов - это поля и свойства, там не может быть никаких переменных, и да, разница огромная.

Comment: @aepot это поле. Это класс logicBase, но на объекте висит TeamShooter который наследуется от него

Comment: Проблема за пределами показанного кода. Давайте не будем играть в угадайку и допрос. Вы не показали ни типов, не кода, с которым ведется работа, только обрубок чего-то, которое находится где-то и делает что-то. Показывайте скрипты целиком или разбирайте сами.

Comment: @aepot у меня там 1000+ строчек.

Comment: В таком случае вам стоит почитать про SOLID, а точнее про SRP в нём, у вас ошибка проектирования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В NetManager вместо

```
LogicBase logicBase = player.GetComponent<LogicBase>();
```

надо было написать

```
LogicBase logicBase = player.GetComponent<TeamShooter>();
```